# Is 'module_script.pl' a Perl idiom for executing 'script.pl'?

Tags: perl

I don't know Perl.  I'm trying to read a Perl script written by someone else.

The script uses the `GetOpt::Long` module.  At multiple points in the code, I see what appear to be calls to other Perl scripts constructed as strings, like in the following:

```
@calls = (
"getopt_AddName.pl -in $first_name -in $last_name -out $full_name",
"getopt_Sort.pl -in $first_name -out $sorted_name -col 1",
"getopt_Join.pl -in $sorted_name -out $all_names_out",
);
```

There **are** scripts in the source code named `AddName.pl`, `Sort.pl`, and `Join.pl`.  However, there **are not** scripts with the "getopt" prefix, i.e. `getopt_AddName.pl`.

All of these are eventually called as Perl programs, without that prefix ever being removed or replaced with anything:

```
while($call = shift(@calls)){
    print "Executing call: $call\n";
    `perl -w $call`; 
    ...
```

Is `module_script.pl`, the use of the module name as a prefix to an external program `script.pl`, some sort of Perl idiom, or is something else going on here?  I can't imagine what else this might be.

I've tried lots of searching, but I can't find any information on this.  It's not in any of the Perl tutorials that I've found.

Comment: Probably just the author's convention, definitely not something you'd see often. I haven't seen anything similar in my 20+ years of professional Perl usage.

Comment: All right, that eliminates one rabbit trail, at least. Thanks!

Comment: Note that instead of using `perl` in the command, you should use `$^X` to get the same perl that you are currently using. Otherwise, you might end up mixing environments.

Answer (score 3):

If `$call` is a string of the form `getopt_AddName.pl ...`, `` `perl -w $call`; `` will only work if `getopt_AddName.pl` exists in the current work directory.

Backtick literals are processed in exactly the same way as double-quoted string literals, and the resulting string is passed as-is to the shell. So you can see what command is executed using

```perl
say qq`perl -w $call`;
```

Since the literal doesn't contain `"` or `` ` ``, this is literally the same as

```perl
say qq"perl -w $call";
```

or

```perl
say "perl -w $call";
```